# Install APK from runtime using Xamarin

Tags: android, runtime, xamarin

I'm trying to make a standalone update solution for a private project. As per a question from StackOverflow, I'm checking versions against an apk on a web server and if there is mismatch am downloading the new .apk, but don't know how to install it from there. Any ideas how this might happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this done before, this snippet might work. The UpdatePackageUri is of type Android.Net.Uri UpdatedPackageUri

```
/// <summary>
    /// Starts the installer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    public void StartInstaller(Context context)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        intent.SetDataAndType(UpdatedPackageUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        context.StartActivity(intent);
    }
```